# What happens if I have two different cards that give me an extra turn after this one?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, I play [Emrakul, the Aeons Torn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Emrakul%2C%20the%20Aeons%20Torn). That gives me an extra turn after this one. Then I activate [Ral Zarek](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ral%20Zarek)'s ultimate and only get one extra turn (one) heads. Will the *Emrakul*'s extra turn meld with *Ral Zarek*'s so I only get 1 extra turn, or will I get two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get two extra turns.

> 500.7. Some effects can give a player extra turns. They do this by adding the turns directly after the current turn. If a player gets multiple extra turns or if multiple players get extra turns during a single turn, the extra turns are added one at a time. The most recently created turn will be taken first.

Comment: How did you turn the card names into hyperlinks?

Comment: @BolasStone, `[mtg:Card Name]`. (Fails for cards with apostrophes because of a bug in Gatherer.)